# Access Laravel Resource Controller from HTTP Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm implementing a small project to maintain a list of books. I'm using PHP 7, Laravel 5.5, Eloquent and SQLite.

I created a Model class `book` and the respective resource controller `BookController`. For the sake of simplicity, a book only has to public properties: title and author.

Furthermore, I created an `AdminController` that creates an admin page. I want to use this page to add books to the database and remove other ones.

My `BookController` has a store() function:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request...
    $book         = new Book;
    $book->title  = $request->title;
    $book->author = $request->author;
    $book->save();
}
```

My `AdminController` has a HTML form with input fields for new books (one for title, one for author) as well as a submit button. This button calls `AdminController@post`.

Now I wonder how to actually add the book from there.

Should I call the `BookController` from the `AdminController` and pass the request object to the `BookController`? Is this the way, controllers communicate in Laravel? Or should I avoid the `store` function and add the functionality to the `AdminController` directly?

Answer (score 0):

- I think you should separate two controller for two purposes. You can declare variable as `Book` model in other controllers and work with it.
- You can using `BookController` for both, just need to define two routes for one controller and write some logic in the store method, my viewpoint... that is not good way. Because it need check some vars to detect which request from admin and from user. I don't want to make some thing complex between workflow of user & admin.